# Mapping a list of objects from application.yml with custom "root key" in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have setup the following configuration class for a Spring Boot application:

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "tasks")
@Getter
@Setter
public class TaskConfiguration {
    
    private List<TaskEntry> tasks;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class TaskEntry {
        private String name;
        private String url;
        private String cronExpression;
    }
}
```

The `application.yml` defines the following values which can be read correctly in the application:

```yaml
tasks:
    tasks:
    - name: A
      url: http://localhosta
      cronExpression: 1 2 3 4 5 A
    - name: B
      url: http://localhostb
      cronExpression: 1 2 3 4 5 B
```

However, you might have noticed that there is a duplicated `tasks` key in the configuration file. I couldn't find out yet how to get rid of it so that the YAML would look like this:

```yaml
tasks:
    - name: A
      url: http://localhosta
      cronExpression: 1 2 3 4 5 A
    - name: B
      url: http://localhostb
      cronExpression: 1 2 3 4 5 B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`ConfigurationProperties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.html#prefix--) `prefix` is *the prefix of the properties that are valid to bind to this object* and in your case it means that *tasks* will be the prefix of all your configuration class properties including the *tasks* property that appears in your application.yml file. To avoid this situation **you can use `@ConfigurationProperties` instead of `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "tasks")`.**

Comment: That was too simple :-)

Comment: @RobertStrauch :-)

Comment: For some reason, I can't get it to work without a prefix. I get: "Failed to bind properties under '' to com.whatev.TaskConfiguration"

Comment: @JWoodchuck I recreated the example with spring 2.6.3 and it works fine, my doubt is if you are using the second yaml file and class provided by the OP.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks. I'm using 2.3.1.RELEASE. Perhaps it was fixed in a later version.

Comment: @JWoodchuck You are welcome, this is certainly possible because I answered using spring 2.5 so I excluded all previous versions from test.

Comment: Thanks so much! Upgrading to 2.6.3 indeed resolved this. What's strange is IntelliJ (2021.2.3 Ultimate Edition) still warns on @ConfigurationProperties that "Prefix must be specified". Maybe a bug in IntelliJ? Pretty frustrating.

Comment: @JWoodchuck You are welcome again :-) , I'm using netbeans so no warnings, there is an IntelliJ issue opened [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-219436) and the funny thing is that OP linked the question...